# Display Image on a button from a URL in swift

Tags: swift

I need to display the background image of a button by giving the image source from an external URL instead of downloading the image. Is there a possible way to do this in swift.

Comment: You mean you want to download and attach the image at runtime rather than during development?

Comment: Yes.. I need to display image on the button at runtime using a image url.

Comment: pod 'SDWebImage', pod 'Kingfisher'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SDWebImage POD.

```
yourBtn.sd_setImage(with: <#T##URL?#>, for: <#T##UIControl.State#>, completed: <#T##SDExternalCompletionBlock?##SDExternalCompletionBlock?##(UIImage?, Error?, SDImageCacheType, URL?) -> Void#>)
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get the image data from external URL and then use the image

```
if let url = URL(string: "YOUR-IMAGE-URL-HERE") {
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                self.imageVar = UIImage(data: data)
                if let myImage: UIImage = self.imageVar {
                    YOUR-BUTTON-NAME.setImage(myImage, for: .normal)
                }
            }catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Saurabh is there a way without downloading the image data because I have about 50 images to download in one view controller and it takes time to download all of them and show in the view.

Comment: Fetching data synchronously, especially on main thread, is always a bad idea.

Comment: mag_zbc then what's your suggetion to do this effectively?

Comment: @TharinduPradeep You have to download the images if you want to display them.

Comment: @mag_zbc Feel free to make necessary changes in my answer.